# _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID error, and it break to xmemory: void dellocate

Tags: visual-c++

I have a block of code that compile in DevC++ in C++ ,but in VSC++, it raised _Block_type_is_valid (phead->...) error and when I retry and break, it went to `xmemory` and function `void deallocate(pointer _ptr, size_t type)`. What's my problem? And how to solve it?

Edited:

I have a `Base` class and a `Base1` class that inherited from `Base` class:

```
class Base{
    public:
            virtual string getString() = 0;    
};

class Base1:: public Base2{
    private:
        char * message;
    public:
        Base1(string _message);
        ~Base1(); 
        string getString();
};
//Base1.cpp

Base1::Base1(string _message){/*Do coppy from _message to message*/}
Base1::~Base1(){delete[] message;}
```

the function `getString()` will return the `message`, and in `main.cpp` i called `Base *b = new Base1("something")` then called `b->getString()` and that's all. However when compiling, i got the problem as describe above. Is this i miss the destructor of `Base` class? or something like this?

Comment: We can't see the constructor but surely you did something unwise like not allocate memory for the char*.  The *message* member should be std::string

Answer (score 0):

You do not show the Base1 constructor. I think the problem is in the Base1 constructor.
You can implement Base1 constructor like this:

```
Base1::Base1(string _message){ message = strdup(_message.c_str()); }
```